# How to find the vertical midpoint of a Gimp image or canvas?

Tags: gimp, images, alignment

How can I locate the vertical midpoint of a gimp image? I searched online and found [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/gimp-find-midpoint-arbitrary-division-between-two-points), but it didn't give me the simple, step-by-step solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After a few more minutes searching, I found the answer. So for anyone else who has this question I want to post a simple concise step-by-step explanation.

[image]

Script-fu window for setting vertical or horizontal guides by percent

1. Make sure you have Gimp open with an image of some sort on the
   canvas.
2. Image > Guides > New Guide (By Percent).
3. If you don't see a Script-fu dialog box, switch between active windows until you
   find it (in Windows use ALT-TAB).
4. In the "Direction" drop-down
   choose "Vertical".
5. Ensure that "Positon" is set to 50% and click
   "OK".

And that's it! If you followed the instructions you should now have a vertical line bisecting your image, in the exact middle of the canvas.

PROTIP: If you follow the procedure again, but this time choose "Horizontal", you will now be able to locate the exact midpoint of your image in all directions.

Comment: i was expecting a menu option that said something like 'Draw Grid on canvas' with a dialog asking for number of rows and columns, allowing 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 or even 2x3,4x5 etc. but i can do the percentage calculations and make each of those lines too. just a matter of patience. (i might call that hard work too) an easy way round? folks, gotta be there. it's mid 2018 already.

Comment: @computingfreak IKR ... They did just release Gimp 2.10 about a month ago... Maybe there is something useful in there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st_mENbhGUk ... Otherwise, there is probably a plugin. Please report back if you find an easier solution

Answer (score 1):

Solution without explicit guides: several "Transform" tools (Scale, Shear, Rotate...) have built-in guides, and one of the option for these is "Center lines", so just start the Tool and just set the option (unless you need to know where the center is when using these tools).

Of course using real guides is often a good idea. If you find yourself routinely adding guides at the same place (center lines, for instance), have a look at [ofn-preset-guides](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) that lets you define your favorite guides sets and makes them available with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: +1 - Thanks! I was not aware of the tools you mentioned having built-in guides. I will check out the plugin/extension you mentioned. Could be just what I need.